# Unable to install bcrypt-ruby 3.1.1

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to install GitLab, but I'm unable to do this:
`bundle exec rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production`

The error I get:
`Could not find bcrypt-ruby-3.1.1 in any of the sources`

Trying to install bcrypt seperately gives me this:
`Parsing documentation for bcrypt-ruby-3.1.1
unable to convert "\x90" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/bcrypt_ext.so, skipping
1 gem installed`

I'm on CentOS

Comment: what version of ruby and rubygems are you using?

Comment: @phoet ruby 1.9.3p448 & gem 1.8.23